# Connection time out, Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I am getting below error while doing mvn insatll. I did almost everything to resolve it like:Force Update,I deleted the /.m2 folder as well.**Not using any Proxy as well**, also checked the /user/.m2/settings.xml file. **What else I could do please help?** I have also added my POM.xml file below.

**Error:**

```
[INFO] --------------------------------[ war ]---------------------------------
Downloading from central: https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] BUILD FAILURE
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[INFO] Total time:  28.775 s
[INFO] Finished at: 2020-05-22T18:36:39+05:30
[INFO] ------------------------------------------------------------------------
[ERROR] Plugin org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:2.6 or one of its dependencies could not be resolved: Failed to read artifact descriptor for org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:jar:2.6: Could not transfer artifact org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-resources-plugin:pom:2.6 from/to central (https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2): Transfer failed for https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2/org/apache/maven/plugins/maven-resources-plugin/2.6/maven-resources-plugin-2.6.pom ProxyInfo{host='172.19.217.26', userName='null', port=8080, type='https', nonProxyHosts='null'}: Connect to 172.19.217.26:8080 [/172.19.217.26] failed: Connection timed out: connect -> [Help 1]
[ERROR]
```

**Pom.xml**

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.aman.emi</groupId>
    <artifactId>Dev-portlet</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <name>productionstatus-portlet</name>
    <version>1.0</version>  
    <properties>
        <faces.api.version>2.2</faces.api.version>
        <liferay.faces.bridge.ext.version>5.0.0</liferay.faces.bridge.ext.version>
        <liferay.faces.bridge.version>4.0.0</liferay.faces.bridge.version>
        <mojarra.version>2.2.13</mojarra.version>
    </properties>
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <encoding>UTF-8</encoding>
                    <source>1.8</source>
                    <target>1.8</target>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            <plugin>
                <artifactId>maven-war-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.3</version>
                <configuration>
                    <filteringDeploymentDescriptors>true</filteringDeploymentDescriptors>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>
    <dependencies>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/oracle/ojdbc6 -->
        <!-- <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-simple</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.22</version>
        </dependency> -->
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/com.github.noraui/ojdbc7 -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-fileupload</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-fileupload</artifactId>
            <version>1.3.1</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>commons-io</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-io</artifactId>
            <version>2.4</version>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
</project>
```

Comment: This is a network issue `failed: Connection timed out: connect` in particular with your proxy: `ProxyInfo{host='172.19.217.26'`...(In contradiction to what you have written. You are using a proxy..)

Comment: Thanks you so much!! Actually I forget to comment my proxy in settings.xml. You saved my day,

Comment: BTW: I strongly recommend to upgrade the plugin version cause they are a little bit out of date...